# How to get all possible tags or pos for a word in spacy

Tags: python, spacy, spacy-3

I am trying to get all the possible tags for a specific word in spacy. For example, still can be adjective or adverb. I want to be able to get both. How is this accomplished? I have searched all over the internet and got no answer. It seems it assumes the user wants only one tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

spaCy isn't like a big dictionary with data about words, the models label words **in context**. So spaCy is not able to do what you want.